# Demovir produces an empty output

Tags: sequence-annotation, covid-19, metagenome, taxonomy, virus

I am new to bioinformatics and am working on viral metagenomic (virome) datasets and so would like to use [Demovir*](https://github.com/feargalr/Demovir) for doing taxonomic annotations on my viral contigs.

First, I installed all prerequisites in my macOS but I found that Usearch 32-bit version could not run on macOS Big Sur, so I installed all and re-ran `demovir.sh my.viral.contig.fasta threads` in ubuntu VM. I could therefore successfully obtained trembl_ublast.viral.u.contigID.txt as an input for R, but I would always get an empty output after performing the demovir.R command of demovir.sh in ubuntu VM.

Thus, I took these back to my macOS, used conda to create a virtual environment for R-3.5.1 and installed R using `conda install -c r r=3.5.1`, then ran `Rscript demovir.R trembl_ublast.viral.u.contigID.txt`. Again, I got an empty output with only showing the headers of five columns.

I also tried to modify the demovir.sh script by removing all previous parts I've completed and retaining the last command `Rscript $DIR/demovir.R`then ran `modified.demvir.sh my.viral.contigs.fasta threads`again, but still got the same result.

Hopefully anyone can do me a favour to check and resolve this issue.

Many thanks.

Ernie

---

Quoting the GitHub repository:

> "Democratic taxonomic classification of viral contigs to Order and
> Family level
>
> When performing metagenomic sequencing of Viral-Like Particle (VLP),
> the majority of returned sequences often bare little to no homology to
> reference sequences - Viral Dark Matter. Frequently it may be useful
> to know which viral taxonomic group these novel viruses are likely to
> belong to as this will give information about nucleic acid type, size
> and behaviour."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> maybe you can open the demovir.R file with Rstudio and execute line by line to check where the failure is. - @zorbax

Thanks for your suggestion. I eventually got a correct final output already.

The key issue was Prodigal would add extra strings after my original contig IDs, so it would cause R not recongnising my viral contigs. Therefore, I added a flag `-trunclabels` in Usearch (after e-value flag) to truncate my contig names. Finally, I re-ran the demovir.sh in ubuntu VM and it has worked well.

Ernie